# How to implement Content Search Web Part in SharePoint Modern experience?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, content-search-web-part

In the classic experience i found this official MS documentation ([link here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configure-a-content-search-web-part-in-sharepoint-0dc16de1-dbe4-462b-babb-bf8338c36c9a)), my question is how can I do the same in the Modern experience ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint Online modern experience, [Highlighted Content Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd) is the successor of content search web part. 
You can use it to do similar thing much easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to install an open source community built solution, the office dev PnP has a set of [Modern Search](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-solutions/releases/tag/ms-2019-10-30) webparts.

Answer (score 0):

After I searched, I just find out how to do it, it seems in SP Modern Experience, they have name it **Highlighted Content**, you can write there your query there and get what you want.